# BBC BASIC: Search for a string in a string

Tags: basic, bbc-micro

I have to write in BBC Basic at school (which I know nothing about) and have to write a program that searches for a string within a string.

Comment: So write it! what's stopping you? go learn it....assignments are given for a reason....

Comment: What @MitchWheat said. This is school, and that's an assignment. You're not going to break anything, no heads are going to be kindly removed from their shoulders, and a lot will be learned if you try and err.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `INSTR` function.

I never heard about BBC BASIC before, but your school should provide you documentation about it if it forces you to learn that BASIC. But at this basic level, all BASIC dialects are very similar. Even if you don't find anything about BBC BASIC, you can try any tutorial about Visual Basic, QBasic, Turbo Basic, GWBasic etc.